# Where can I buy Isobutane/Propane fuel for my camping stove in Calama, Chile? Are there any outdoor stores or camping stores there?

Tags: camping, chile

I'm heading into the Atacama and would like to pick up camping supplies in Calama, Chile.  Does one buy butane/propane canisters at a gas station or are there outdoor stores?  Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, The Great Outdoors SE may have folks who have done something like this...

Answer (score 3):

A place to find gas canisters for camping stoves is Homecenter Sodimac. They mostly sell furniture, materials and work tools, but they also store some gas canister sizes for outdoor camping stoves.

The Calama store is located at [Avenida Balmaceda 3398](https://goo.gl/maps/Z7n5vr1aFtiAYrP4A), right inside of Mall Plaza Calama.